# SCSS @import mixin in React imported style

Tags: reactjs, sass, create-react-app, mixins, scss-mixins

I'm trying to use SCSS in my React App made by Create React App.
I have file called mixin.scss that I need to import in SCSS file, usually I used Ruby Compass and this just worked;

```
@import '_mixin';
```

but using `node-sass` in React app from CRA it doesn't seem to be working.

What can I do for that to work?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like `@import` was replaced by `@use` and Node-sass is old, currently preferred implementation is Dart-sass (`yarn add sass`) so hopefully I'll be able to convert my apps to Sass package simply...